# Laravel Simultaneously input one to many in database

Tags: laravel

I have a card, this card has tags. So a Card has many tags and a Tag belongsTo a Card.

A user fills a form. He gives both the information for the card aswell as the tags.

Now I need to give each tag the information 'card_id' so it can be connected.

Now is my problem that I don't know this 'card_id' yet because the database did not yet assign a id as they are both being created simultaneously.

My situation:

```
  public function create(Request $request)

  {

$this->validate($request,[
   'function' => 'max:255',
   'description' => 'max:255',
   'rate' => 'max:255',
   'location' => 'max:255'
]);

$card = new Card;
$card->user_id = Auth::id();;
$card->function = $request->function;
$card->description = $request->description;
$card->rate = $request->rate;
$card->location = $request->location;
// I also tried this:     $card->tag()->saveMany($tagsArray); (Did not work)
$card->save();

$tagsArray = explode(',', $request->tagsarray);

foreach($tagsArray as $tagInput) {

  $tag = new Tag;
  $tag->card_id = 'Cant know this yet :(';
  $tag->tag = $tagInput;
  $tag->save();
}

return redirect('/page');

  }
```

Does someone know how to go about this?

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is never good.. use package for this... https://laravel-news.com/2015/10/how-to-add-tagging-to-your-laravel-app/

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```php
$card = new Card([
    'card_name' => request()->get('card_name'),
    'something_else' => request()->get('something_else')
]);

if($card->save()) {

    $tags = [];

    // Get the tag information from request
    $tagsFromRequest[
        ['tag_title' => 'A Tag', 'tag_slug' => 'a_tag'],
        ['tag_title' => 'Another Tag', 'tag_slug' => 'another_tag']
    ];

    foreach($tagsFromRequest as $tag) {
        $tags[] = new Tag($tag);
    }

    $card->tags()->saveMany($tags);
}
```

Now, prepare your tags from request where each tag item should be an array as given above and I can't be more specific because you gave nothing that you've tried and which might help me to understand your scenario. [Check the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models).

Comment: I have added my scenario to the question. I indeed tried to work with saveMany however that does not seem to work when you did not yet made the cards instance. So i Try to wrap my head around your scenario right now.

Comment: Since tags are related to card, card should be **already** inserted to your database in order to be synced (you can use the method sync() while updating models).